# prepareforseque trouble displaying my variable in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get my label in my viewcontroller 3 to show the variable from the integer input from a text box in viewcontroller 1. 
Unfortunetly I can't get this to work.

In my first viewcontroller I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var shotAttempts: UITextField! //This is my  text box where the variable is typed I want to display in viewcontroller 3.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : nextlevelnow = segue.destinationViewController as! nextlevelnow
    DestViewController.shotsTaken = shotAttempts.text!

//nextlevelnow is my ID for my viewcontroller 3. 
}
```

Then in my class for my viewcontroller 3 I have the code:

```
  @IBOutlet var stats: UILabel! //This is the label I want to show my variable created in the shotAttempt textbox from my other viewcontroller.

  var shotsTaken = String()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }


  @IBAction func check(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("check: \(shotsTaken)")
    stats.text = shotsTaken
  }
```

Comment: Actually this code is supposed to work. Is the action connected properly? Add a print line or breakpoint with log action to check.

Comment: @vadian It doesnt give me an error, I just can't see the print on screen anywhere... however when I set the var = string() could this be a problem? as my variable from the shotAttempts.text is integer. 

I'm not sure what you mean by print line or breakpoint with log action, I have never used log action before.. still fairly new to using xcode.

Comment: The `text` property of a text field returns always `String` even it seems to be an integer. Add the line `print(shotsTaken)` within the `check` method. This checks the value of `shotsTaken` as well as the method is called at all.

Comment: @vadian I apologies for being ignorant.. but I'm not sure when you say "check method". Do you mean under my action button? (I just did) No error but still can't see anything on my screen, however before and after this the text of my label that is set to begin with does go away after the click of my button, however it does not change to my textfield input (as you already know)

Comment: I edited your code to make it clear and added some custom text. If nothing is printed the button is not connected to the action in Interface Builder.

Comment: It still does not show anything, it just removes the original label text.
The button works fine, because it does more things which works, I just took that out of the code to make it more simple to show here. @vadian

Comment: Again: if nothing is printed out, the method `check:` is not called. At least `check: ` should be appear in the console. Your code is supposed to work if everything in interface Builder is set up properly.

Comment: It must be some interface/layout issue then, I'll take a look on it tomorrow and come back with either the answer or some more information.  Thanks for your time and help so far!

Comment: I found out if I write: stats.text = "check: \(shotsTaken)"

I get on screen: check: nil

Any idea why shotsTaken is nil? @vadian

Comment: I got "nil" because I had set a "!" after the variable like this:  String!()
I took that away so its like my original code, and now its show "check" but nothing else..

Comment: I answered this post first but found out I was wrong, not sure if I can delete my answer? I tried, but it looks like its still there.

Comment: @vadian been struggling with it all day, still haven't found a solution. If I write: stats.text = "check: \(shotsTaken)" I get on screen: Check

Comment: Again, the code looks correct. Set breakpoints and/or insert other `print()` lines to print out variables. Xcode has powerful debug tools

Comment: This is the time Im trying prepareforseque, could I have set the seque connection wrong in the interface somehow? I just dragged the seque from viewcontroller 1 to my viewcontroller 3. @vadian 

And I'm sorry for taking so much of you time, I really do appreciate the patience.