# Undertanding prepareforsegue in swift correctly

Tags: ios, swift

Earlier I uploaded my code where I have tried to use prepareforsegue, and the response was my code was correct and I have written and setup up prepareforsegue in my code correct.

But it still didnt work for me, so I figured maybe I haven't understood prepareforsegue correctly.

This is what I was trying to do with prepareforsegue:

If I have my viewcontroller 1, and through out my app you click on a label that makes the user go to viewcontroller 2, and then another label is clicked and you get to viewcontroller 3 (this is the viewcontroller where I want a printed  variable from a textfield in viewcontroller 1)

I thought could my problem be, that prepareforsegue does not work when you click on labels? do you have to use the "next tab" in the right corner, which I have seen used in the tutorials I have tried to undertand the prepareforsegue from?

Comment: are you actually using UILabels or UIButtons? labels arent clickable (well unless you subclass a UILabel and make it clickable)

Comment: Yes I am, and everything else is working fine in my app. I get to viewcontroller 3, and I do it by the criteria I have set for my textfields..
And in my viewcontroller 3 class xcode recognize my variable from viewcontroller 1, but when I try to print it nothing comes out... and if I try to print it as a int it says: nil

Comment: As I understood the segue function, you just put your mouse cursor on your viewcontroller and hold "ctrl" and then take your cursor and release it on the top of the other viewcontroller where you want to display your variable in (in my case viewcontroller 3)

Comment: im not sure i quite follow, but prepareForSegue lets you setup the next viewcontroller. if you are setting the actual labels in vc3 from vc2 in prepare for segue that wont work. you cant set the labels before viewDidLoad in vc3 is called, which is after prepareForSegue in vc2. so what you should do is pass the values to vc3 as temporary variables, then in viewDidLoad in vc3, set the labels to those temp variables. maybe link your previous question so i have some frame of reference where you are coming from

Comment: If I undertand what you saying I really think this could be my problem! this is the link: (dont look at my answer, that was a mistake (tried deleting it)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847840/prepareforseque-trouble-displaying-my-variable-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment55484038_33847840

I want my input form a textfield in vc1 to be shown in vc3, however the steps to get to vc 3 in my app is start in vc 1, then vc 2, and then vc 3.

Comment: it seems like you just need `stats.text = shotsTaken` inside vc3 viewDidLoad (after the super call), but depends if `shotAttempts.text!` in prepareForSegue in vc2 is set correctly, should put some breakpoints and make sure all the values are set correctly when it hits those lines of code

Comment: shotsAttempts.text! is in vc1! (i think this is the problem somehow, that im preparing a segue from vc1 to vc3, but since I go through vc2 to get to vc3, it won't work?)

I know my shotAttempts.text! works, as you can't go to the next vc without its input meet some criteria I have set.

Comment: ye then it seems like you passed the variables to vc2, but then not to vc3, you will need another prepare for segue in vc2 to pass it onto vc3

Comment: Okay, I'm coming back home in a few hours and I'll try to change the code / add another segue, I will let you know what happens. I really appreciate the help! thank you.

Comment: @Fonix I can't get it to work. Do you mind telling me exactly how this would work? 

First I set prepareforsegue in my vc1 to vc2. Where I set my shotAttempts.text = testvariable (and testvariable = string ())

Then in vc 2 I prepareforsegue  I set: testvariable = anotherVariable (anotherVariable = string())

and then in vc3 I print "anotherVariable"

But I dont get my shotsAttempts.text... I just get nothing on screen..

Comment: so when you print `anotherVariable` in vc3 it shows the proper value, but the label in vc3 is not showing the text?

Comment: no, anotherVariable is not showning anything.

In theory It should show my shotsAttempts.text input from the user on vc1, but its shows nothing.

I want the user to type a integer in vc1 in my shotsAttempt textfield, and then in vc3 I want to print this integer.

Comment: put breakpoints where ever you assign the values and just see what is being set where so you can see whats going on, find out exactly where your chain of passing the variable is breaking down and go from there i guess. i cant really help you without having the code

Comment: Can I have messed up in the interface when setting up my segues? I just dragged my VC while holding ctrl down to my VC2, and then my VC2 to my VC3

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had to use "button" to click to go to the next vc for it to work, I kept using my "label" as thats how I made my app, that you had to click on a label to go to the next vc.